# How do i put a link in a table

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a table on my website, which gets data from a database, in the table I have delete buttons on a row, I have just made the table searchable with jQuery, but now I can't figure out how to keep the delete buttons.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Inventar">
    <meta name="author" content="Martin Eide Bjørndal">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/style.css">
       <!-- jQuery library -->
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button class="back" onclick="window.location='../'">
      <img src="/src/icons/back.png">
    </button> <!-- Tilbake knapp -->

    <button class="ny_inventar" onclick="window.location='/admin/brukere/ny'">
      <img src="/src/icons/add.png">
    </button> <!-- Ny Bruker knapp -->

    <div class="container-fluid" id="utskjekkcontainer">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-mv-10 bg-light mt-5 rounded p-3">
          <h1 class="text-primary p-2">Brukere</h1>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <label for="search" class="font-weight-bold lead text-dark">Søk</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search_text" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary" placeholder="Søk...">
          </div>
          <hr>
          <?php
            include "../../src/fn/init.php";
            $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM brukere");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result=$stmt->get_result();
          ?>
          <table class="table table-hover table-light table-striped" id="table_data">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Fornavn</th>
                <th>Etternavn</th>
                <th>Utskjekket</th>
                <th>Admin</th>
                <th>Slett</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["fornavn"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["etternavn"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["utskjekket"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["is_admin"]; ?></td>
                  <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Er du sikker?');">Slett</a></td>
                </tr>
              <?php }
              $conn->close();
              ?>
             </tbody>

           </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
          var search = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{query:search},
            success:function(response){
              $('#table_data').html(response);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

action.php:

```
<?php

    include "../../src/fn/init.php";
    $output = "";

    if(isset($_POST["query"])){
        $search = $_POST["query"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM brukere WHERE fornavn LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR etternavn LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR id LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$search, $search, $search);
    } else {
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM brukere");
    };
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $output = "<thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Fornavn</th>
                    <th>Etternavn</th>
                    <th>Utskjekket</th>
                    <th>Admin</th>
                    <th>Slett</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";

        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["fornavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["etternavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["utskjekket"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["is_admin"]."</td>
                    <td>".<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Er du sikker?');">Slett</a>."</td>
                </tr>";
        };
        $output .= "</tbody>";
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo "<h3>No match found!</h3>";
    };


?>
```

This is the search script, the problem is in the while loop where the link is added, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Explain better. The link is added but it doesn't work? What appears on the page at the link location? Do you have any kind of error?

Comment: @AksJacoves In the index.php file the links get added, and it works perfectly, but when i search the table, and the action.php file returns the new table i cant get the links to work. The error im getting is en unexpected < in action.php where im trying to add the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` tag is not added as a plain-text to the `output` string, you need to rewrite that line, concatenate strings parts to variables parts correctly.

Try replacing:

```
$output .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["fornavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["etternavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["utskjekket"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["is_admin"]."</td>
                    <td>".<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Er du sikker?');">Slett</a>."</td>
                </tr>";
```

with:

```
$output .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["fornavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["etternavn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["utskjekket"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["is_admin"]."</td>
                    <td><a href='delete.php?id=".urlencode($row['id'])."' onclick='return confirm('Er du sikker?');'>Slett</a></td>
                </tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow PHP to echo the id from the table result you need to just simply do a php echo

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Er du sikker?');">Slett</a>
```

You don't have to url encode at this stage as you are just simply building the href of an a:link

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
<?php

include "../../src/fn/init.php";
$output = "";

if(isset($_POST["query"])){
    $search = $_POST["query"];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM brukere WHERE fornavn LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR etternavn LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR id LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$search, $search, $search);
} else {
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM brukere");
};
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows>0){
    $output = "<thead>
                <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Fornavn</th>
                <th>Etternavn</th>
                <th>Utskjekket</th>
                <th>Admin</th>
                <th>Slett</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";

    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["fornavn"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["etternavn"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["utskjekket"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["is_admin"]."</td>
                <td><a href=\"delete.php=".urlencode($row['id'])."\" onclick=\"return confirm('Er du sikker?');\">Slett</a> </td>  
            </tr>";
    };
    $output .= "</tbody>";
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "<h3>No match found!</h3>";
};
```